# Entry point not found on DLL import

Tags: c#, pinvoke, dllimport

Trying to use a third-party native DLL from C#, I am getting the exception that the DLL entry point was not found and I have no idea what the reason is.

`dumpbin /exports` gives me the following symbol: `?Foo@@YA_NPBDII0II_NMEEE01PAE@Z`. I resolved this with `undname` which returns: `bool __cdecl Foo(char const *,unsigned int,unsigned int,char const *,unsigned int,unsigned int,bool,float,unsigned char,unsigned char, unsigned char,char const *,bool,unsigned char*)`

Therefore, i tried to import the function like this:

```
[DllImport("FooDll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)] // evtl. __thiscall?, Charset?
    private static extern bool Foo(string name, uint x, uint y, string app, uint width, uint height, bool switch, double factor,
        byte r1, byte g1, byte b1, string store, bool switchBack, [In, Out] byte[] result);
```

I also tried with `CallingConvention = CallingConvention.ThisCall` and without the charset parameter, but the same exception occurs.

Any idea where to look?

Comment: If I remember correctly, if the dll is not compiled with `EXTERN "C"`, `LoadLibrary` doesn't automatically handle mangling. This means you should load the function using the mangled name. Let us know if this helps.

Comment: @WiktorZychla with setting the `EntryPoint = "?Foo@@YA_NPBDII0II_NMEEE01PAE@Z"` I receive an `AccesViolationException` so I guess this means that the function is called but something else is causing another problem

Comment: Consult the documentation of the library to find out how to call it

Comment: @DavidHeffernan unfortunately there is not such a documentation. Otherwise, I would not need to ask the question here

Comment: Close, but no cigar.  Entrypoint is required, double should be float.  Right now the stack frame is off by 4 so when it tries to access the result parameter it is going to keel over.  Be careful with that array, there doesn't seem to be a way to tell it how large it is so you have to guess at the required size.  Guessing too low will corrupt the GC heap, very nasty.  Aim high.

Comment: @HansPassant the combination of float and entry point solved the problem

Comment: @royalTS: Yes, the `AccessViolation` means the stack frame is corrupted, glad it's been resolved. Since it's been a team effort, you could possibly write your own answer.

Comment: You still won't know how to call the function. Knowing its signature is not enough. Why are you using DLLs in this way?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The question is not about how to work with this DLL, but the question was how to solve my entry point problem. And this is solved by the helpful comments of the others

Comment: @HansPassant The array size is determined by the width and height parameter

Comment: No. That's why I commented because my comment wasn't an answer. Bit still, knowing the signature is not enough to know how to call a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of Wiktor and Hans, the entry point problem was solved:

It was necessary to specify an entry point as a parameter for the `DllImport` attribute with the mangled/ decorated name as it seems that the DLL does not use the `extern C` declaration. Furthermore, the type of the `factor` parameter must be `float` (`System.Single`) to match the expected parameter length on the stack. So the C# code looks like this now:

```
[DllImport("FooDll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "?Foo@@YA_NPBDII0II_NMEEE01PAE@Z")]
private static extern bool Foo(string name, uint x, uint y, string app, uint width, uint height, bool switch, float factor,
    byte r1, byte g1, byte b1, string store, bool switchBack, [In, Out] byte[] result);
```